# in if else Loop ,cannot drop the same temp table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

i am using if else statement and ,i want to drop the temporary table which is created out side the inner if statement , but when i execute the statement , i get the answer as , There is already an object named '#table' in the database. ---------------------MY CODE IS LIKE enter code here

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT;

SET @RowCount = 1;

IF @RowCount = 1
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Guarantor_Details') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #Guarantor_Details

    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 GUARANTORS.GUARANTOR_CODE
    INTO #Guarantor_Details
    FROM GUARANTORS
    WHERE ISNULL(GUARANTORS.deleted, 0) <> 1;

    DECLARE @GuarantorCount INT;

    SELECT @GuarantorCount = count(*)
    FROM #Guarantor_Details;

    IF (@GuarantorCount = 0)
        DROP TABLE #Guarantor_Details

    BEGIN
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Guarantor_Details') IS NOT NULL
            SELECT TOP 1 CLIENT.Last_Name
            INTO #Guarantor_Details
            FROM CLIENT
            LEFT JOIN GUARANTORS ON GUARANTORS.GUARANTOR_CODE = CLIENT.Financial_Guarantor
    END
END
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this type of CREATE / DROP. You can (and probably should) create the table before the loop and simply either `TRUNCATE TABLE` or `DELETE FROM` the temp table when necessary to "reset" it. Just pick a datatype that fits both `GUARANTOR_CODE` and `Last_Name`.

You also don't need to do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` on the table when you have the `@@ROWCOUNT` from the `INSERT` operation that already has that value in it.

Essentially:

```
CREATE TABLE #Guarantor_Details (Value NVARCHAR(50));

WHILE (something)
BEGIN

  IF (@RowCount = 1)
  BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE #Guarantor_Details;

    INSERT INTO #Guarantor_Details (Value)
      SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 GUARANTORS.GUARANTOR_CODE
      FROM GUARANTORS
      WHERE ISNULL(GUARANTORS.deleted, 0) <> 1;

    IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO #Guarantor_Details (Value)
        SELECT TOP 1 CLIENT.Last_Name
        FROM CLIENT
        LEFT JOIN GUARANTORS
               ON GUARANTORS.GUARANTOR_CODE = CLIENT.Financial_Guarantor;
    END;
END;
```

FYI, there *appear* to be some logic problems in the original code:

- There are BEGIN / END tags at the bottom of the `IF @RowCount = 1` block that aren't associated to any IF or WHILE. This is technically ok, but usually implies something is missing.
- If this code is all of the code, then the `IF @RowCount = 1` doesn't work in the loop unless something sets `@RowCount` past the end of this outer IF block that is not shown here in the question.